# designing a algorithm for a large data

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I read one of this question being asked for a job interview of software engineer.

If there are 1000 websites and 1000 users, write a program and Data-structure such that i can query for the followin at real time: 1. Given any user, I get the list of all sites he/she has visited 2. Given any website, I get the list of all users who have visited it.

I think they wanted sort of a pseudo code or designing algorithm..

Can you guys give any tips for this?

Comment: There are only a million points to consider here.  In most situations these days I do not think that is a large enough data set to warrant 'clever' treatment.

Answer (score 3):

One thing is certain - in order to be able to answer both queries, you need to store all the pairs  which mean that the user has visited the given website. So what I propose is the following:

You have a structure:

```
struct VisitPair{
  int websiteId;
  int userId;
  VisitPair* nextForUser;
  VisitPair* nextForWebsite;
};
```

nextForUser will point to the next pair for the given user or NULL if there is no next pair for the given user, similarly nextForWebsite will point to the next pair for the webSite. User and website will look something like:

```
struct User {
  char* name;
  VisitPair* firstPair;
};

struct Website {
  char* url;
  VisitPair* firstPair;
};
```

I assume both Website-s and users are stored in arrays, say these arrays are `websites` and `users`. Now adding a new visitPair is relatively easy:

```
void addNewPair(int siteId, int userId) {
  VisitPair* newPair = (VisitPair*)malloc(sizeof(VizitPair));
  newPair->nextForUser = users[userId]->firstPair;
  users[userid]->firstPair = newPair;
  newPair->nextForWesite = websites[siteId]->firstPair;
  websites[siteId]->firstPair = newPair;
}
```

Printing all users for a website and all the websites for a user is done by simply iterating over a list so you should be able to do that.

In short what I create is a structure that has two lists integrated. I do not think there can be a solution with better complexity as this one has linear complexity with respect to the answer and constant complexity for adding a pair.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For each web site and user, keep a linked list for visitors and web sites visited, respectively. Whenever a user visits a web site, add an entry in the user linked list as well as the web site linked list.

This has minimal memory overhead and a fast updates and queries.

Comment: +1. It would be good to explicitly mention that 2 arrays are needed, one for websites and one for users, each element of which is a (pointer to a) linked list. Both websites and users must be identified by integers numbering up from 0.

Answer (score 3):

Since both number of sites, and number of users are bounded and known in advance, you can use a 2D array of 1000 x 1000 dimension, with user being one dimension ,and website being another.
The array would be a boolean array.

```
bool tracker[1000][1000] ;
```

when user x visits website y, it is marked as 1 ( true ).

```
tracker[x][y] = 1;
```

To return all users who have visited website J,
return all values in column J , which have value 1,

to return all websites visited by user i, return all values in row i, which have value 1.

The complexity of lookup is O(n) , but this approach is space efficient, and updates are 0(1), 
unlike linked list which would require O(n) complexity to add a user to website  linked list, or to add a website to user's linked list.(But that gives a O(1) complexity when doing lookups).

Comment: I am sorry but I do not agree to this answer. THe approach is not space efficient as it always uses 1000* 1000 memory no matter the number of pairs. Also adding to the linked lists is actaully constant. Read my answer.

Comment: @izomorphius I partially agree with you, but considering high number of possible events of website visits, 1000x1000 booleans 1 bit each, would be better than nodes.

Comment: Whether or not this makes efficient use of space, or whether it is more or less space-efficient than a linked list approach, kind of depends on data that none of us has -- the density (or sparsity if you wish) of the matrix.  So we make assumptions ...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Correct. But overhead of memory allocation and pointer manipulation for each tracking,compared against updating a preallocated boolean value is also something to consider.

Comment: for 1000x1000 i would take the matrix every time. simple, takes like 5 lines of code, but i am gonna wrap it in some interface, in case this moves to 1 milion users for example

Comment: since this is just a binary yes/no as to whether there's a relationship you can compress this into a bitmap, if space is an issue; poof, O(1) lookup for single relationship, O(n) lookup for sites<->users mappings, in less than 1/4 MB

Comment: I'd fail a candidate if they gave this solution. It takes a vast amount of memory if nobody visits anywhere, and as a solution for a project in use in a company **it's not extensible** (e.g. adding visit counts, recording URLs clicked, referrers, etc.) without consuming even more vast amounts of memory. Top flight companies won't be hiring anybody that causes them to re-implement every time they need to extend the system.

Comment: Not a big deal, but this does ignores the need - worth a brief mention - to map from a user and website to associated index numbers: sorted arrays, hash tables and binary trees are all reasonable solutions.  Separately to @aps2012: it can equally be important to separate real-time needs from other data that might have lower performance requirements - reading so much into this choice of implementation is less useful than - as an interviewer - asking about alternatives and implications for maintainability.

Comment: @TonyDelroy This particular answer was given with no justification except for the speed; nothing business related. You can't just drop solutions out of thin-air (or, for that matter, pinch them from the answers of a StackOverflow question) without a justification. If this solution had been stated with an _intent_, and bounds for its intended use, then conversely, the candidate would be showing that he is aware of the _limits_ of his design. That passes interviews in flying colours. The OP said it was an interview question, therefore an interview-style response is expected.

Comment: this is simply not scalable.. though the question mentions 1000, in real life you rarely see these hard limits.

Answer (score 1):

In general case with **N** users and **M** sites have two maps for queries like

```
map<user, set<site> > sitesOfUser;
map<size, set<user> > usersOfSite;
```

When user **u** visits site **s** you update this with

```
sitesOfUser[ u ].insert( s );
usersOfSite[ s ].insert( y );
```

**set** is used here to avoid duplication. If duplication is ok (or you will take care of it later), you can have just **list** and reduce update time by another **log**.
In this case update will take **O( logN + logM )** time ( or just **O( logN )**, see above) and query will take **O( logN )** time.

In your particular case when the maximal number of sites and users is not too much and is known beforehand (let's say it's **K**) you can just have two arrays like

```
set<site> sitesOfUser[ K ];
set<user> usersOfSite[ K ];
```

Here you will get **O( logN )** time for update (or **O(1)** if duplicated information is not a problem and you use **list** or some another linear container), and **O(1)** time for query.

Comment: You've written "O( logN * logM )", but isn't it "O( logN + logM )" instead?

Comment: Also, with this data structure, update is indeed O(logN + logM), but "get the list of all sites she has visited" os Θ(M), as this is the length of the answer.

Comment: @jrouquie: Thanks, fixed first issue. But I will disagree with the second one - you get the answer (more precisely - a pointer to the answer) in O( logN ) and Θ(M) will be the time required to copy it, which I didn't consider as a part of the query.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a summary of posted answers**.

Let m be the number of sites, n the number of users.
For each data structure we give the complexity for update, resp. get.

- two arrays of linked lists. O(1), resp. O(len(answer)).
- an m×n matrix. O(1), resp. O(m) or O(n). The least memory usage if most users visit most sites, but not optimal in space and time if most users visit only a few sites.
- two arrays of sets. O(log m) or O(log n), resp. O(len(answer)).

izomorphius's answer is very close to linked lists.

O(len(answer)) is the time required to read the whole answer, but for sets and lists, one can get an iterator in 0(1), that has a `next` method which is also guaranteed O(1).

Comment: Good, but I think izomorphius's answer uses the same amount of memory as 2 separate linked lists (assuming no fixed per-`malloc()` overhead).  `VisitPair` can be split into 2 `struct`s each having 1 ID and 1 next-pointer, and each instance of it in a program run corresponds to 1 instance each of these `struct`s.